# Update widget's TextView with API data

Tags: android, widget, android-widget

**INTRO**

My objective is to set a TextView's text to a string I get from an API using Volley and JSON.

The function getData() seems to work properly (checked Logcat).

**PROBLEM**

At the moment when the API returns its values, the updateAppWidget(...) has already passed through and the TextView text is already set to "" (which is the default static value). If I add the TextView inside a Thread, it will not work because of the Threading nature.

**STRATEGY**

I need a way to make the updateAppWidget(...) function to wait some seconds until the value is withdrawed from the API. Or is there any better option?

The only files I edited are the one I've attached here and the AndroidManifest (just to allow intenet).

Thanks in advance.

```
package com.bosswell.samplewidgetapi;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    static String value ="";

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

        getData(views, context);

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, value);
        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.d("INFO", "onUpdate");

        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        Log.d("INFO", "onEnabled");
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

    private static void getData(RemoteViews views, Context c){
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(c);
        String url ="https://www.worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Moscow";
        Log.d("INFO", url);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject j = new JSONObject(response);

                            value = j.getString("datetime").toString();
                            Log.d("INFO", value);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            value = e.getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                value = error.getMessage();
            }
        });

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're doing such API dependent activities repeatedly you can look at the MVVM and observer which is the recommended way of doing it

Comment: Use AsyncTask to call API, then try to update widgets

Comment: @Style-7 how could I sequence the code to FIRST call the API and only THEN (when finished) try to update the widgets? If possible, provide a formal response and I will try to work on it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set value in `TextView` on your

> OnResponse

Method like this

```
               @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject j = new JSONObject(response);

                        value = j.getString("datetime").toString();
                        yourTextView.setText(value.toString());
                        Log.d("INFO", value);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        value = e.getMessage();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The change implied to pass the views as a parameter, which I did, but didn't work.

Comment: There is no setText for widget for Home screen.

Answer (score 0):

1. Extend `AsyncTask` for call to API. In method `doInBackground` try to connect to internet, then update widgets by `AppWidgetManager`.
2. Add to onUpdate method

   ```
    @Override
    public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds ){
        super.onUpdate( context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds );

        new AsyncTaskUpdater(context).execute(...);
    }
   ```

So, method onUpdate do not update widgets.